# Don't step into library code with Flutter and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Is there a solution on how to stop stepping into external library code, while debugging? In Visual Studio Code you have the option to set: "debugExternalLibraries". Is there a similar option for Android Studio?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Is there a solution for this? Is it possible to use  

Android Studio > File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Debugger > Stepping

and then filter out dart and flutter libraries?